# Prove that finite boolean groups are isomorphic to $(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^n$

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Prove that finite Boolean groups are isomorphic to $(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^n$

If possible, use only the group theory to resolve this question.

My approach is as follow: Let $G$ be an Boolean group and let $D$ be the group $(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^n$.

1. Prove that it exists an homomorphism from $G$ into $D$, that is, it exists a mapping $f$ from $G$ to $D$ such that $f(a.b) = f(a)f(b)$ for all $a$ and $b$ in $G$.
2. Prove that the Kernel of $f$ is $(e)$.

I see that there is a strong correspondence between $G$ and $D$, but I do not manage to prove it formally using the mapping $f$. Thank you for your help.

Comment: This is true if we assume a *finite* Boolean algebra.  For the general case there is the Stone representation theorem.

Comment: Yes sorry.. I did not specified that the group G is finite

Comment: Shouldn't it be $f(ab) = f(a)+f(b)$?

Comment: We usually write * to express the operation (as a general notation), but indeed in the group D the operation is the addition of binary strings and you can write +

Comment: What is a "Boolean group"?

Comment: A group in which every element is its own inverse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Hint:* Take $a \in G, a\ne 1$ and let $A=\langle a \rangle$. Prove that $G \cong A \times G/A$. Use induction on $G/A$.

Comment: I suppose G/A means G without A, right?

Comment: @Allure, no, it means the [quotient group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_group).

Comment: I asked because I thought initially that it was quotient group, but it made less sense than G\A... now I will have to think more, but still thanks